# Cron job not working Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, cron

For some reason, I cannot get a simple cron job working on my Mint 18 KDE system.

This is the job, it tells a script to run every minute. See the crontab line that I get when I type `crontab -l`:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
1   *   *  *   *     sh /home/martien/crontest.sh
```

This is the script `crontest.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /home/martien/archives/
DIRECTORY='webcam-'`date +%y-%m-%d-%H-%s`
mkdir ~/archives/$DIRECTORY
```

These are the properties of the script

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 martien martien  110 Apr  2 07:35 crontest.sh
```

The file in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` confirms the existence of the cron job.

Cron runs:

```
root       953     1  0 06:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

The script runs when I enter this in the command line:

```
sh /home/martien/crontest.sh
```

I run Mint 18 (Ubuntu Xenial).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `cron`  entry runs once an hour, at one minute past:

```
 1 * * * * sh /home/martien/crontest.sh
```

If you want every minute you should use this:

```
 * * * * * /home/martien/crontest.sh
```

Since you've declared your script to be a `bash` script and you've set it to be executable, just call it directly. Don't write a `bash` script and use `sh` to execute it as on some systems they really are different shells.

Your script can be amended slightly, too:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/martien/archives
DIRECTORY="webcam-$(date +'%y-%m-%d-%H-%s')"
mkdir "$DIRECTORY"
```

I've quoted your variables when they are used, and switched backticks to the more modern and consistent `$(...)` construct.

Comment: Yay! It works like a charm.